# writing an array output to perl with new line

Tags: perl

I am getting  an output from a subroutine as

```
 @ outputarray

outputarray[0]=name  ip  port 
outputarray[1]=------------------------------------ 
outputarray[2]=http-listener-1  *   6712
outputarray[3]=http-listener-2  *   4743
...... etc
```

I want to create a  new file and write to  file log.txt where file content looks  as below and delete the file log.txt  how can I achieve this in perl?

```
 name ip port 
------------------------------------ 
http-listener-1 *      6712 
http-listener-2 *      4743
```

Thanks

Comment: pls. post your so far code.

Comment: You want to write to log.txt and then delete log.txt? Sounds redundant, don't you think?

Comment: Yes I have one more subroutine to scan the port I will delete it after that

Comment: I assume that your number 4743 changing to 8709 in the output is just a typo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How to open a file and print an array to it:

```
open my $fh, ">", "log.txt" or die $!;
print $fh "$_\n" for @outputarray;
close $fh;
```

How to delete that file:

```
unlink "log.txt" or die $!;
```

Why you would want to first print and then delete that file, I have no idea.

Comment: Sorry i am newbie to perl  does your first line also creates new file?

Comment: `>` is the open mode that creates a new file, yes. And it also overwrites any old file with that name.

Comment: where can I get more information about the syntax used in the print statement?  It makes sense to me, but as a perl newbie, I didn't know you could use it that way in a print statement.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html